# How to use pandas melt to convert multiple columns to rows

Tags: python, pandas

I  have a data set as below in excel

```
   A              B       C           D         E           F        G
1                SKU                 Units                Sales
2               11/5/18  12/5/18    11/5/18   12/5/18    11/5/18   12/5/18
3 Description                       total=5   total=9    total=33  total =60
4 Nail Varnish   2345     2345          2       4          $15      $30
5 Eyeliner       2346     2345          3       5          $18      $30
```

I am using pandas to convert it to another excel with below structure

```
    Description     date          sku           Units          Sales             
0   Nail Varnish    11/5/18       2345            2            $15 
1    Eye liner      11/5/18       2346            3            $18
2   Nail Varnish    12/5/18       2345            4            $30 
3    Eye liner      12/5/18       2346            5            $30
```

I have used melt function in pandas earlier to convert one column to row (for example either sales or Units) and i dont know if it works for three multi index columns.

```
df = pd.read_excel(filepath_name,index_col=False,usecols="A:G")
df2=pd.melt(df,id_vars=["SKU ","Units","Sales"], var_name ="Date", value_name='?)
```

But how can i convert my all there id vars(SKU, Units and Sales ) at one go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Idea is created index with first column and MultiIndex by first 2 rows, so possible use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = pd.read_excel(filepath_name,index_col=[0],usecols="A:G", header=[0,1])

print (df.columns)
MultiIndex(levels=[['SKU', 'Sales', 'Units'], ['11/5/18', '12/5/18']],
           codes=[[0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])


df = df.stack().rename_axis(('Description','date')).reset_index()
print (df)
    Description     date   SKU Sales  Units
0  Nail Varnish  11/5/18  2345   $15      2
1  Nail Varnish  12/5/18  2345   $30      4
2      Eyeliner  11/5/18  2346   $18      3
3      Eyeliner  12/5/18  2345   $30      5
```

If second values are missing in excel file need preprocessing:

```
print (df)
                 SKU Unnamed: 1_level_0   Units Unnamed: 3_level_0   Sales  \
             11/5/18            12/5/18 11/5/18            12/5/18 11/5/18   
Nail Varnish    2345               2345       2                  4     $15   
Eyeliner        2346               2345       3                  5     $18   

             Unnamed: 5_level_0  
                        12/5/18  
Nail Varnish                $30  
Eyeliner                    $30 

a = df.columns.get_level_values(0)
b = df.columns.get_level_values(1)
a = a.where(~a.str.startswith('Unnamed')).to_series().ffill()
df.columns = [a, b]

print (df)
                 SKU           Units           Sales        
             11/5/18 12/5/18 11/5/18 12/5/18 11/5/18 12/5/18
Nail Varnish    2345    2345       2       4     $15     $30
Eyeliner        2346    2345       3       5     $18     $30
```

EDIT1:

If need filter only some columns for reshape:

```
cols = ['SKU','Units','Sales']
df = df[cols].stack().rename_axis(('Description','date')).reset_index()
print (df)
    Description     date   SKU Sales  Units
0  Nail Varnish  11/5/18  2345   $15      2
1  Nail Varnish  12/5/18  2345   $30      4
2      Eyeliner  11/5/18  2346   $18      3
3      Eyeliner  12/5/18  2345   $30      5
```

EDIT1:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['SKU ', 'Units', 'Unnamed: 0_level_0', 'Sales'], 
                            ['11/5/18', '12/5/18', 'Unnamed: 0_level_1'], 
                            ['total=5', 'total=9', 'total=33', 'total=60', 'Description', 'Unnamed: 1_level_2', 'Unnamed: 2_level_2']], codes=[[2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3], [2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [4, 5, 6, 1, 0, 2, 3]])

df = pd.DataFrame([range(7),range(7)], columns=mux)
print (df)
  Unnamed: 0_level_0               SKU                       Units          \
  Unnamed: 0_level_1            11/5/18            12/5/18 11/5/18 12/5/18   
         Description Unnamed: 1_level_2 Unnamed: 2_level_2 total=9 total=5   
0                  0                  1                  2       3       4   
1                  0                  1                  2       3       4   

     Sales           
   11/5/18  12/5/18  
  total=33 total=60  
0        5        6  
1        5        6
```

---

```
a = df.columns.get_level_values(0)
b = df.columns.get_level_values(1)
c = df.columns.get_level_values(2)
#forward fliing missing values
a = a.where(~a.str.startswith('Unnamed')).to_series().ffill()
b = b.where(~b.str.startswith('Unnamed')).to_series().ffill()
#repalce missing values by empty string
c = c.where(~c.str.startswith('Unnamed'), '')

df.columns = [a, b, c]

#convert first column to index
df = df.set_index(df.columns[0])
df.index.name='Desc'
print (df)
        SKU            Units            Sales         
     11/5/18 12/5/18 11/5/18 12/5/18  11/5/18  12/5/18
                     total=9 total=5 total=33 total=60
Desc                                                  
0          1       2       3       4        5        6
0          1       2       3       4        5        6
```

---

```
#reshape and rename columns names
d = {'level_0':'a','level_1':'dates','level_2':'b'}
df = df.unstack().reset_index(name='vals').rename(columns=d)
print (df)
        a    dates         b  Desc  vals
0    SKU   11/5/18               0     1
1    SKU   11/5/18               0     1
2    SKU   12/5/18               0     2
3    SKU   12/5/18               0     2
4   Units  11/5/18   total=9     0     3
5   Units  11/5/18   total=9     0     3
6   Units  12/5/18   total=5     0     4
7   Units  12/5/18   total=5     0     4
8   Sales  11/5/18  total=33     0     5
9   Sales  11/5/18  total=33     0     5
10  Sales  12/5/18  total=60     0     6
11  Sales  12/5/18  total=60     0     6
```

Comment: just to add, what if i have more date values, should i insert all into the multiindex  like MultiIndex(levels=[['SKU', 'Sales', 'Units'], ['11/5/18', '12/5/18',13/5/18,14/518......]] or is there any alternative

Comment: @Tejas - yes, sure. Main problem here is create `MultiIndex` from first 2 rows, my solution working? What return `print (df.columns)` in your data?

Comment: Hi, i try to run, but am getting the error , cannot specify usecols when specifying a multi-index header, how to troubleshoot this

Comment: @Tejas - Are data confidental? Because really hard solve your problem without yoyur excel, if confidental data need only first data row and header (be free change values to some samples like `aaa`, `bbb` )

Comment: my excel data is same as that of first table in my question

Comment: @Tejas - Is possible read all data to DataFrame and filtering later? Like my last EDIT1 solution?

Comment: i've tried the second part then the first , its almost working except for Description column i'm getting indexes(0,0,1,1,2,2) instead of product names(Nail varnish and eyeliner etc)

Comment: @Tejas - Hard to find problem for me, because cannot see real data. with sample data for me it working perfectly.

Comment: updated the structure, my headers span across 3 rows and the cells with total have to be ignored

Comment: @Tejas - In sample data is necessary change `header=[0,1]` to `header=[0,1,2]` for read first 3 columns to 3 level `MultiIndex`

Comment: the description column still  populates indexes and not actual values, other columns are getting populate correctly

Comment: @Tejas - hmmm, it seems some proprocessing is necessary, how looks `print (df.columns)` ?

Comment: MultiIndex(levels=[['SKU ', 'Units', 'Unnamed: 0_level_0', 'Sales'], ['11/5/18', '12/5/18', 'Unnamed: 0_level_1'], [total=5, total=9, total=33, total=60, 'Description', 'Unnamed: 1_level_2', 'Unnamed: 2_level_2']],
           codes=[[2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3], [2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [4, 5, 6, 1, 0, 2, 3]])

Answer (score 0):

[`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.melt.html) is opposite to [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.pivot.html).

> and i dont know if it works for three or multi index columns.

Yes, it works for multi index columns. If columns are a MultiIndex then use `col_level` parameter to melt.
The examples are provided in the first link.